# Where are files saved while debugging a Silverlight 5 Application in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: debugging, silverlight-5.0, internet-explorer-10, iis-express

I have some code that saves an xml file to the file system.

```
    public static void Save(T obj, string FileName)
    {
        if (Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
        {
            string myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(myDocuments, FileName);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot Save File. Application Requires Elevated permissions.");
        }
    }
```

While debugging using Internet Explorer 10 the file is not saved to the listed path in the path variable "C:\Users\Travis\Documents\Save.xml"

I call load with the exact same path "C:\Users\Travis\Documents\Save.xml" and the file loads correctly but the file still does not exist at the listed location.

I searched the file system with no results for Save.xml but it has to exist since it is able to load after application exit.

If I access the same page using Chrome the file is created successfully at the location.

I am wondering where Internet Explorer saves the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I uncheck "Enable Protected Mode" in IE's Security tab then the file is created in the location as expected.